# No puedo resolver esto en JavaScript sin usar indexOf

Tags: javascript

Agradezco si me pueden ayudar con este ejercicio, que no sé como resolverlo :(

```
function index() {
  
// Escribi una función encontraIndex en el prototipo de Arrays,
  
// que recibe un elemento.
  
// La function tiene que devolver el indice (index) del primer elemento que coincida con el pasado como parametro dentro del array.
  
// Si el elemento se repite dentro del Array, este devuelve el indice del Primer elemento.
  
// Si no existe ese elemento la funcion debe devolver -1
  
// NO USAR LA FUNCION indexOf DE LOS ARREGLOS.
  
// ej:
  
// var numeros = [5, 6, 4, 65, 8, 4]
  
// numeros.encontraIndex(4) debe devolver 2.
  
// ya que el numero 4 se encuentra en la posicion 2 dentro del array.
  
// numeros.encontraIndex(23) debe devolver -1 ya que ese elemento no existe en ese array.
```

No debo modificar los argumentos de la función además. Gracias de antemano

Esto es lo que intenté hacer:

```
numeros.encontraIndex = function(){

    for (var i = 0; i <= arguments; i++) {
        if (numeros[i] === arguments) { return i}

    }
}
return -1;
```

Acaso podría usar .findIndex?

```
    let numeros = [5, 6, 4, 65, 8, 4];
    let n = 4
  
    for (let i = 0; i < numeros.length; i++) 
        console.log(numeros.findIndex(numeros[i] === n));
    }
```

No me funciona así

Comment: Tengo una forma de hacerlo pero creo que no será eficiente con arreglos muuuuy grandes

Comment: Como sería esa forma?

Comment: @jigglypuff9 podrias poner lo que has intentado?

Comment: ahí lo subí como respuesta

Comment: Aquí tienes la [documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) de como utilizar __findIndex__

Comment: Bienvenidx a SOes. Como sugerencia, procura siempre decir algo más detallado que "no me funciona". Trata siempre de contarnos a los demás con qué datos de entrada pruebas, qué salida obtienes, qué salida esperabas obtener, qué mensajes de error te salen, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Prueba con algo como esto:

1. Primero definimos la función dentro del arreglo, como lo indican las instrucciones.
2. Luego hacemos el bucle de búsqueda utilizando this (porque ahí están los valores) y el argumento recibido.
3. Si lo encontramos, devolvemos la posición. No necesitamos seguir buscando porque dice la instrucción que solo importa el primero.
4. Si no lo encontramos, termina el bucle y regresamos -1.

```js
var numeros = [5, 6, 4, 65, 8, 4];

// esta es la función de búsqueda
Array.prototype.encontraIndex = function(valor) 
{
    // como estamos dentro del arreglo, this contiene los valores
    for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) 
    {
        if (this[i] === valor)
        {
            return i;
        }
    }   
    return -1;
}

// probamos la rutina
var posicion = numeros.encontraIndex(4);
if (posicion != -1)
  console.log("El valor está en la posición: " + posicion);
else
  console.log("El valor no está en el arreglo");
```

Saludos

Comment: Buena respuesta, pero soluciona a medias el problema; solo va a servir con el arreglo `numeros` porque la función no se define como método del prototipo de `Array`.

Comment: Hola @Triby, lo hice de esa manera para que fuera simple de entender, pero tienes toda la razón, en un programa real habría modificado el prototipo de Array. Modifiqué el código para reflejar tu propuesta, muchas gracias :)

Answer (score 1):

el ejercicio dice usar prototipos(Prototype) asi que lo que tienes que hacer es agregar la funcion al prototipo arreglo; el ejemplo a continuacion:

```js
Array.prototype.encontraIndex = function(numero){

      for (var i = 0; i <= this.length; i++) {
          if (numero === this[i])return i

      }
  
  return -1; 
 }
var numeros = [5, 6, 4, 65, 8, 4]
  
console.log(numeros.encontraIndex(4), 2)
  
// ya que el numero 4 se encuentra en la posicion 2 dentro del array.
  
console.log(numeros.encontraIndex(23),-1)
```

Answer (score 1):

lo probé varias veces, funciona. Lo pensé de la siguiente forma:

debemos saber si encuentra una coincidencia o no, por lo que definí un atributo booleano llamado "coincidencia" donde su estado inicial es falso, este no cambiará hasta que encuentre una coincidencia. Por lo tanto:

```
const numeros = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
const n = 7;
function index() {
  let coincidencia = false;
  for (let i = 0; i < numeros.length; i++) {
    if (n === numeros[i]) {
      coincidencia = true;
      return i;
    }
  }
  if (coincidencia === false) {
    return -1;
  }
}
```

Espero te sirva amigo!!

Answer (score 0):

La forma seria con ciclo for en el cual se evalúa la posición del arreglo

```
var numeros = [5, 6, 4, 65, 8, 4]

nuumeros.encontraIndex= function () {
    n=4
    for(let i=0; i<numeros.length; i++){
        if(numeros[i]==n){
            console.log(`la posición es ${i}`)
            return i 
        }
         return -1
    }
}
```

Ahora solo llamas a la función `let indice=encontraIndex()` y te deberia dar el resultado con un `console.log(indice)` todo esto funciona correctamente

Comment: Gracias! De todas maneras no puedo agregar argumentos a la función y ahí le estás poniendo n,como podría hacer? Además no está el caso de que si no existe el elemento y retorna -1

Comment: Te encuenta que la OP deberia poner lo que intento porque basicamente le estas resolviendo el ejercicio sin mas

Comment: Perdón, no sabía. Soy nueva. Ahora subo lo que intenté hacer

Comment: Pues si no puedes pasarle argumentos a una función lo quitas y defines n adentro de la función,

Comment: Si, lo hice pero no funciona. Gracias de todos modos

Comment: Ya edite mi respuesta, pruebala

Comment: Tampoco funciona :(

Comment: A mi si me funciona, podrías editar tu pregunta y poner __todo__ lo que has echo hasta ahora

Comment: Yo sospecho que no me funciona al correr el test porque debo hacerlo con .findIndex. Intenté hacerlo así y tampoco funciona de todas maneras, pero quizás porque lo estoy implementando mal. Ahí edito la pregunta

Answer (score 0):

Lo que ocupas en un ciclo que recorra el arreglo, usando la notación de corchetes para acceder al índice de un arreglo puedes saber si es igual o no, también para que no siga recorriendo el cilo utiliza **break**, esto terminara el ciclo.

Te dejo este recurso para que entiendas mejor los arreglos: [ver más](https://eloquentjs-es.thedojo.mx/04_data.html)

```js
let numeros = [5, 6, 4, 65, 8, 4];

numeros.index = (value)=> {
  let res = -1;
  for (let i = 0; i < numeros.length; i++) {
    if (numeros[i] === value) {
      res = i;
      break;
    }
  }
  return res;
}

console.log(numeros.index(4))
// → 2

console.log(numeros.index(23))
// → -1
```

Comment: Buena respuesta, pero soluciona a medias el problema; solo va a servir con el arreglo `numeros` porque la función no se define como método del prototipo de `Array`.

Comment: @Triby Gracias por la observación, tienes razón